# Storing passwords in an encrypted form in hbase

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, hbase, password-hash

I'm storing my database credentials in hbase. Is there any way to store the passwords in an encrypted form? So, when I scan the hbase table the password appears in ****** format.

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the [password-encryption] tag and read what it says. Are you sure your want to do this? You really should be hashing passwords.

Comment: Encrypting passwords is not recommended. Hash passwords with salt to get the best results. Use pepper or prepared statements if the database is open to users to thwart SQL injection

Comment: I am the only person who can write the password into hbase. But, I din't wanted it to be exposed, although my peers can use that hbase entry. Can you provide a way for that?

Comment: Well the answer is simple you should use Hashing but if you really want only asteriks than better to store ***** :D..

Comment: just to clarify: do not simply hash, but use something like scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Thanks everyone... it works